# facebook OG like button, getting an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

This is the meta I use for my facebook Like button.

> ```
> <meta property="og:title" content="Title of the Page" />
> <meta property="og:type" content="tv_show" />
> <meta property="og:url" content="URL of the page with trailing slash" />
> <meta property="og:site_name" content="The general site title" />
> <meta property="og:image" content="link to the thumbnail" />
> <meta property="fb:admins" content="number" />
> <meta property="fb:app_id" content="number" />
> ```

Here is the error I am getting:

> The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to
>   specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or
>   using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of
>   Facebook users.

Can someone please advice? I am following all the guidelines on their like implementation page.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: do you have an app_id.  dont know much about this in the context of html programming

Comment: i dont see it in the code (i understand you dont want to publicly release it) but i take it, it is in the code?  the error is quite plain and to me that seems to be ur problem, but ya, ive only done this on ios

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by adding these namespaces to your HTML tag on your website:

```
<html ...  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Courtesy of: http://blitzkriegconsultant.blogspot.com/